# How to debug Python script(using breakpoint) that is called from Matlab code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, debugging

I am using MATLAB_R2023b.
I have wrote a Python script which is called from Matlab files. I want to debug the Python script. I have tried logging information using print statements in Python but that is not the preferred way to debug as I have to do a lot of work. I wanted to know if there are any work arounds like using visual studio code or other IDE for the same.
I am using MACOS, now that Visual Studio is retiring for MACOS how should one go about debugging it?

I tried PDB for breakpoints in python but it did't help.
I have tried the below solution but it didn't work
[Calling Python from Matlab - how to debug Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708900/calling-python-from-matlab-how-to-debug-python-code)

Comment: you can debug the python code in any IDE (actually an editor) like `VScode`. But where is the code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Related: [1: Requires Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61711276/3978545), [2: Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558828/vs-studio-code-with-python-how-to-debug-coming-from-matlab-vs-code-debugger)

Comment: Have you seen [this MATLAB Answers post](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1645680-how-can-i-debug-python-code-using-matlab-s-python-interface-and-visual-studio-code)?